# Java can't get myself to acquire filename from terminal args[0]

Tags: java, arrays, file, count

I need some help with understanding why my code won't let me put in a filename for it to read, which it then processes. I will paste the code below. I also wonder about one thing: I need the code to check an entire text-file, check an array whether the word is already in it, and then add +1 to a counter-array I got. I haven't been able to test it, so I hope it works! But it would be awesome if someone could just take a quick glance and see if there is anything screaming error in their faces. :)

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Oblig3A{
    public static void main(String[]args){


//The problem is here somewhere I believe:

    OrdAnalyse oa = new OrdAnalyse();
    String filArgs=args[0];
    oa.analyseMetode(filArgs);
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse{
    void analyseMetode(String filArgs){

    //Begynner med aa opprette alle variabler som trengs, disse deklareres rett under. De ligger her oppe bare for at jeg skal ha oversikten over de.
    Scanner input, innfil;
    String[] ord, fortelling;
    int[] antall;
    int antUnikeOrd;
    PrintWriter utfil;

    //Variables..
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ord=new String[5000];
    antall=new int[5000];
    antUnikeOrd=0;

    try{
        innfil=new Scanner(filArgs);
        //Naa skal jeg dele opp prosessen litt for aa faa inn funksjonaliteten for aa for eksempel sette alle ord til lowercase.

        //Here it says that as long as the file is longer, it will continue the while-loop, and for every line it will set 
the words to all lowercase, split the line on blanks, and then fill it into an array called fortelling. 
It will then run two nested for-loops which will make it check the entire ord-array for matches for every word in the fortelling-array, 
and if it finds a match it will increase the count-array antall +1 in the index where the word is found.
 Does it not find anything, it will save the word to the (hopefully) last index in the array, increase that index in antall with 1, and then increase the uniquewordcounter (antUnikeOrd) with 1.
 I hope this part will work out, but I must first be able to get the file...


        while(innfil.hasNext()){
        fortelling=innfil.nextLine().toLowerCase().split(" ");
            for(int i=0; i<fortelling.length; i++){
              for(int j=0; j<5000; j++){
                if(fortelling[i]==ord[j]){
                   antall[j]+=1;
                }else if(!fortelling[i].contains(ord[j])){
                   ord[j]=fortelling[i];
                   antall[j]+=1;
                   antUnikeOrd+=1;
               }
               System.out.print(fortelling[i]);
               System.out.print(fortelling.length);
               }  
           }
           }
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
     }
   }
```

It seems completely unable to open the file... And I don't know why. This will eventually write out all info to another file it creates, but I havent written this part yet.

Comment: Seems this was a bad question since it was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 issues

- Use a `File` argument in the constructor of `Scanner` so that you're not using a `String` source

  `innfil = new Scanner(new File(filArgs));`
- Use `.equals` to compare `String` content. The `==` operator is used to `Object` references.

  `if (fortelling[i].equals(ord[j])) {`
- Lastly this statement

  `} else if (!fortelling[i].contains(ord[j])) {`

will throw an `NPE` as the `ord` array is never populated before being checked. I suggest using a `Map<String, Integer>` rather than an array to store the occurrences of words.

Comment: Hmmm... NullPointerException at line 9, that means the oa.analyseMetode(filArgs)-line O.o

Comment: Yep, not the only issue

Comment: Okay, thanks alot. It was very clarifying as to why I got the NPE now at the line you described. I'll try and find a way to fix it :)

Comment: A different collection is really required here, a `Map` would be more suitable - see update

Comment: If you are interested in helping me sort this out, I would worship you and your firstborns into the next era. This has been bugging me for longer than i'd like to admit. Because. And here is the no-fun: I cannot use HashMaps -.- Not "allowed" to, since my studygroup haven't done the previous chapters. And that is actually a chapter which I can.

Comment: Could I use a String fortelling instead? Make it read one word at a time, check that word, lace it into the correct category and then move on, or is this virtually impossible/too clumsy?